# Tensorflow: _dataset_ops.so not found

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to get into Tensorflow but keep hitting an error:

```
D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\load_library.py in load_op_library(library_filename)
     54     RuntimeError: when unable to load the library or get the python wrappers.
     55   """
---> 56   lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
     57 
     58   op_list_str = py_tf.TF_GetOpList(lib_handle)

NotFoundError: D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\..\..\_dataset_ops.so not found
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

The error seems to be generated by the following call...

```
x = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(x, is_training=is_training, decay=momentum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution for this is to remove `_dataset_ops.so` file from the installation. Solution is taken from [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20320). in short, go to the below location(based on your traceback)

```
D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data
```

you will find a file named `_dataset_ops.so`. delete this file or move it out of this folder and re run the code. This will work